# update mainform control with subform filter

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform that is filterable based off a mainform combobox using parent/child links. It should update a textbox on the mainform with the average of a column on the filtered subform, but I haven't figure out how to do that quite yet.

> I have tried just typing in
>
> =Avg([columnname]) as well as
>
> =Avg([Emergence %],[frmbestfacility].[Form]). I've also used =DAvg but no luck.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here's the setup.
Main form is called "Results Form", the tabbed form on it is called "Tabs", the tab I'm looking at is called "Best Facility" and the form on that is called "frmbestfacility". The column i'm looking at is "Emergence %". Using any of these gets me #Error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
=Avg([frmbestfacility].[Form]![Emergence %])
```

If that doesn't work, create a textbox on the subform, txtAvgEmergence, and set its ControlSource to:

```
=Avg([Emergence %])
```

Then, on the parent, use the ControlSource:

```
=[frmbestfacility].[Form]![txtAvgEmergence])
```

Note, that when you type this in, you may have to use the *localized* name for `Form`

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm not sure what you mean by subform control name. Otherwise, super helpful. **Edit** my subform is just a query.

Comment: For further reference, my combobox, the filter setter, is called cbobestspecies.

Comment: Nvm, i found out what a subform control is. my subform control name is frmbestfacility. This still produces an error though.

Comment: Yeah, this is often tricky. You may have to use a workaround - see edit.